# How to detect modified injected services in karaf?

Tags: dependency-injection, osgi, apache-karaf

I have a service A that depends on service b via dependency injection. Service B runs the @Modified method when it's associated config file is changed. How do I get service A to restart when service B's config file is updated? Maybe there's someway of serviceA retrieving a list of all consuming services?

Service B

```
@Component(
    name = "my.services.ServiceB",
    immediate = true,
    configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE
)
@Designate(
    ocd = ServiceBConfig.class
)
public class ServiceBImpl implements ServiceB {
    public ServiceBImpl() {}

    @Activate
    @Modified
    protected void start(ServiceBConfig serviceBConfig) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Service A

```
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        designateFactory = ServiceAConfig.class,
        name = "my.services.serviceA"
)
public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {
    private ServiceB serviceB;
    private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;

    @Reference
    void setServiceB(ServiceB serviceB) {
        this.encryptionService = encryptionService;
    }

    @Reference
    public void setConfigurationAdmin(ConfigurationAdmin admin) {
        this.configurationAdmin = admin;
    }

    @Activate
    @Modified
    void activate(BundleContext bundleContext, Map<String, Object> configuration) {
        // code
    }
}
```